# Magento block per action

Tags: magento, controller, action, block

I am trying to create a custom collection page with pagination. I have created the code for the pagination in the block and can output it in the template.
However the module that I am creating has pages that have other templates with no pagination.

How it works: User goes to index.php/styles/choose/items and selects the attributes/categories of the products he wants to display. He clicks on submit and is redirected to index.php/styles/choose/products where he can see the products and pagination.

In my styles.xml I have

```
<styles_choose_items>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="styles/styles" name="styles" template="styles/styles.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </styles_choose_items>
    <styles_choose_products>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="styles/products" name="products" template="styles/products.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </styles_choose_products>
```

In config.xml I have :

```
<blocks>
        <styles>
            <rewrite>
                <styles>Nuvo_Styles_Block_Styles</styles>
            </rewrite>
            <rewrite>
                <products>Nuvo_Styles_Block_Products</products>
            </rewrite>
        </styles>
 </blocks>
```

In the controller :

```
 public function itemsAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function productsAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

I would really like to know what I am doing wrong. The index.php/styles/choose/items page displays correctly, however the index.php/styles/choose/products show only the template and if I try to add anything to the Products.php block it goes blank with no error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: activate php's error display and Magento's developer mode: that way you'll see the error and thus understand what's going wrong, first step to the solution

Comment: Hi. I've activated the error logs in Magento and added error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);ini_set('display_errors', 1); to the php file, but I cant find any logs and no errors are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

the declaration of `blocks` in your config is wrong, you are not rewriting blocks, as far as I can tell. Try this:

```
    <blocks>
        <styles>
            <class>Nuvo_Styles_Block</class>
        </styles>
    </blocks>
```

Also it would be useful to see `Nuvo_Styles_Block_Products`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. I've enabled line 77 in index.php ini_set('display_errors', 1); to see the errors.
I was actually very close. There was just an error in the Products.php block file. It now works correctly.